# Deference between assetic-bundle with Asset Management?

Tags: symfony, assetic

what is deference between `assetic-bundle` in `vendors/symfony` with [Asset Management](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AsseticBundle integrates Assetic with Symfony. Assetic itself is a standalone PHP library that can be used in any PHP project — not just with Symfony.

Comment: So is Assetic available in `Symfony_Standard_Vendors_2.1.3.tgz`?

Comment: @MohammadAliAkbari The Symfony Framework is the core framework of symfony. It includes some bundles but NOT the assetic bundle. However, most of the time you will use the Symfony Standard Edition which includes The Symfony Framework and some bundles (assetic is one of them). You downloaded the Symfony Standard edition with vendors and assetic should be in there.